# remove data if they repeated 3 times (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two table one for the data and the second one for duplicate data in first table

Imagen that inside first table :

```
<tbody id="Data">
<tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>2</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>2</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>3</th>  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I use this function to remove duplicate data

```
function reoveDuplicateFramTable(){
 $("#duplicateData").empty(); 
 var seen = {};
 $('#Data tr').each(function() {
 var txt = $(this).text();
 if (seen[txt]){  $("#duplicateData").append($(this)) }
  else{ seen[txt] = true  }
});}
```

and the second table will be like this:

```
<tbody id="duplicateData">
  <tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
  <tr> <th>2</th>  </tr>
</tbody>
```

how about if i wand just to remove duplicate data if they repeated 3 time?
the second table be like this:

```
<tbody id="duplicateData">
 <tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
</tbody>
```

is that possible in Jquery?

Comment: check :contains(value) in jquery and calculate output length for each element found.

Comment: sorry .. I'am beginner could you explain that by edit in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use your `seen` object as a counter instead of just setting `true`, then check the count on each row iteration.

I'm not 100% clear on what you expect the behavior to be so am appending any rows to duplicate table that already have two matches

```js
function reoveDuplicateFramTable() {
  $("#duplicateData").empty();
  var seen = {};
  $('#Data tr').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text().trim();
    seen[txt] = (seen[txt] || 0) + 1

    if (seen[txt] > 2) {
      $("#duplicateData").append(this)
    } 
  });
}

reoveDuplicateFramTable()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="Data">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Duplicates</h3>
<table>
  <tbody id="duplicateData">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// loop through table
$("#Data tr").each(function() {
// find duplicates that contains same text
   let elements = $("#Data tr:contains("+$(this).text()+")")
//check if length is greater than 2 then remove those add in duplicates table
   if (elements.length > 2){ 
// add duplicate element
      $("#duplicateData").append($(this).html())
// remove all duplicates from #Data 
      elements.remove()
   }
})
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="Data">
<tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>1</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>2</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>2</th>  </tr>
<tr> <th>3</th>  </tr>
</table>

<table id="duplicateData">
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Code wise this appears simpler than a tracking object but all those extra DOM queries are a lot more expensive, especially on larger table

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, you are absolutely right but give the fact that he is a beginner I think solution will work for test projects.

Comment: Best practices shouldn't be determined by level of understanding